# What does (DW) mean in the TI equivalent of SOIC (16) package?

Tags: components, texas-instruments, industrial, naming-conventions

[TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7830.pdf?ts=1705903125105&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) says:

> SOIC-16 Wide Body (DW) and Extra-Wide Body (DWW) Package Options

It doesn't mention what DW stands for.

I am annoyed when manufacturers come up with their own naming conventions without explaining clearly the accronymns or the logic behind the naming. How does one remember/navigate these part numbers while selecting the right part for your application if the naming convention is not standard or clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapter 1 of the data sheet gives us a clue:

> SOIC-16 Wide Body (DW) and Extra-Wide Body
> (DWW) Package Options

So the "W" stands for "wide", and "WW" for "extra wide". It is the same pattern as clothing, where "X" stands for "extra" and "XX" for "extra extra". X-D

The "D" might stand for "dual-in-line".

Comment: I think this is a good answer because it addresses the etymology. But it would be better with a note saying that these manufacturer-specific abbreviations do not really matter. They are keys to find manufacturer-specific documents (should you need them), but 99.999% of the time it is prudent to treat them as the respective manufacturer-agnostic package, which is SOIC in this case.

Answer (score 6):

In general these are references to manufacturer-specific package designs. They may or may be identical or similar enough to those other manufacturers use, you have to check yourself if you are substituting. **If you're trying to use an existing footprint in your EDA package it's up to you to determine if its usable, optimal or whatever.**

In this particular case, the DW0016B leads us to [this](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/SOIC16DW.pdf) document, in which TI has provided "example" land patterns, solder mask and solder paste patterns. There are  disclaimers as well, not as strong as "recommended"-- I guess their lawyers were in play.

[image]

[image]

Since this is an isolator, the layout is particularly important and the details appear to be duplicated on the datasheet, but that's not always true.

Sometimes you can find additional documents that list more details of the various materials used, but they can be specific to the assembly site, of which there may be more than one, or they may be revised over time (for example, bonding wire composition).

Comment: The land patterns are just examples, because a chip manufacturer cannot possibly know what is a good land pattern in the process the chips are soldered. Usually fabs that put the components on the board can suggest a land pattern that suits their process best, for least problems and optimum amount of solder for the pads by suggesting stencil openings too.

Comment: Sure, but many manufacturers use the term "recommended", for example Onsemi: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/solderrm-d.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The "Device Information" box on the first page of the datasheet show that the DW package is 10.3 x 7.5 mm, whiile the DWW package is 10.3 x 14 mm.

Section 13 of the datasheet has dimensioned drawings of the two packages and an addendum lists the full part numbers of the various versions that are available to order.

Answer (score 4):

> How does one remember/navigate these part numbers while selecting the right part for your application if the naming convention is not standard or clear?

By reading the datasheet, like for any other IC-specific property. In this case there is a very explicitly named "mechanical, packaging..." section in the table of contents, which contains detailed drawings.

Answer (score 2):

Every manufacturer has their own discipline to mark packages and their drawings. Technically the "DW" does not stand for anything very meaningful, just a designator for particular drawings. Every time you need to check/verify if you are using right package, some package variants may even have completely different pinout, INA219 for example, which is pretty annoying.